# org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition.setRole(I)V when @EnableKafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition.setRole(I)V

this happened when set @EnableKafka in configration class

maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Spring module version mismatch.
As per [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html#setRole-int-), the `BeanDefinition#setRole` method exists from `5.1`.

So check your `org.springframework.spring-beans` dependency. `Spring Kafka 2.2.3.RELEASE` requires Spring `5.1.4`

Now that you updated your question, upgrade your `spring-webmvc` and `spring-security-config`

```
spring-webmvc          5.1.4.RELEASE
spring-security-config 5.1.3.RELEASE
```

Comment: after add spring beans i got new error :
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: logger

Comment: @Najeisleem Wait, maintain the original Maven dependencies, just update the ones I wrote above.

Comment: @Najeisleem Awesome! Remember that Spring modules' (org.springframework) versions must always match on the minor version number, in this case 5.1